# relative width container with 1 absolute width float and 1 relative float

Tags: css, layout, html

I've read a lot of answers but am not sure why it is just not working for me. Maybe it has something to do with the parent container not being 100%? the things is...i also tried it with padding, but the same problem exists.

I've also tried container=width:100%, and create the 10% spaces with margins in the floating divs, but the 10% created was of an odd scale...definitely not proportionate to the page.

here's the code.

```
.container{
width:80%;
overflow:hidden;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
}

.side{
width:300px;float:left;}

.main{
position:absolute;  float:left;  }

.clear{clear: both;}
```

(without the absolute the two divs are no longer side by side...but i saw people using relative here????)

and here is the html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

So the problem right now is that for some reason the div "main" will not fill up the remaining space but the text inside will either stop before it reaches the border of the "container" or ignore the container at all and stretch beyond the page...

**I would like to keep the blank margins on the sides, and need one of the floating divs to be a fixed width...not sure why its not working**

....I feel like there is a easy solution to this I'm just not thinking straight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve.. Are you trying to re-flow the HTML on page for accessibility?

For starter, to make .main to stay inside .container, put this in the .container:

```
position:relative;
```

Then maybe you are trying to float main to the right of side.. put this in .main

```
left:300px;
```

Hope I guessed your intent correctly..

Comment: after adding position relative to container and left:300px, main is where I would like it to be. I tried overflow auto and hidden, but overflow text just disappears?

Comment: overflow is first set by .container, so try changing overflow setting there first. Secondly, your .main likely will need some kind of width set, or a absolute positioned div won't know how wide it should be. If it does not know how wide it is, you can't overflow things.

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like this:

```
.container {
width:100%; / width: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

.side {
width: 60%;
float: left;
}

.main {
width: 40%;
float: left;  
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

in `.container` pick width % or px's... what is more flexible for u